# Is it possible to load Parquet data directly from memory?

Tags: rust, rust-polars

I have a use case where I will be downloading Parquet data directly into memory (*not* into the filesystem). Is it possible to load these files as (lazy) dataframes from a `Vec<u8>`? instead of passing in the path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```rust
use polars::prelude::*;
use std::io::Cursor;

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let mut df = df![
        "a" => [1, 2, 3]
    ]?;

    // write to buffer
    let mut buf = vec![];
    ParquetWriter::new(&mut buf).finish(&mut df)?;

    // read from buffer
    let reader = Cursor::new(&buf);
    let result = ParquetReader::new(reader).finish()?;

    // validate result
    df.frame_equal(&result);
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: This answers a completely separate answer too!: How to write a parquet file into a vec of Bytes to be consumed by a file file upload process (e.g. s3 `PutObject`)?